# Delete items from document library based on criteria just like WHERE clause in SQL statement

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, caml

Is there a way to delete items from a document library based on some criteria for e.g. delete all documents whose created date is less than 1/1/2012.

I know it can be done through code but I am looking for some other way like powershell command just like we write an SQL statement such as:

```
DELETE FROM mylibrary WHERE created <= '1/1/2012'
```

Comment: You can create Powershell script to loop through the documents and delete, I'm afraid this one-liner statement isn't available AFAIK

Comment: check this if solve the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519374/script-to-delete-files-older-than-a-day-in-sharepoint-document-library

Answer (score 0):

mmm try this script:

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sitecollectionURL") 
$web = $site.rootweb 
$list = $web.Lists["Name of the List"]

$caml='<Where>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2011-12-31T02:32:20Z</Value>
        </Leq>
    </Where>'

$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$query.Query=$caml | Write-Output

$items=$list.GetItems($query) 
$listItemsTotal = $items.Count;

for($x=$listItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{
        $items[$x].Delete()
}

$web.Dispose() 
$site.Dispose()
```

Good Luck